# Are there open source audio stream clients or frameworks?

Tags: c++, c, objective-c, audio

I'm looking for how to play back audio streams in these formats:

- MP3
- Ogg / Vorbis
- WMA over MMS/ASF
- AAC / AAC+

target is the mac and iPhone. Maybe there is an open source library that I could look at, to understand how it works, and then port it to the cocoa frameworks somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd take a look at [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/). It's the most widely used opensource codec library and can be compiled for the iPhone. It has RTSP support (Microsoft deprecated MMS streams in 2003 and most current mms:// streams are actually just RTSP.

You don't actually need to port C/C++ libraries to Cocoa to be able to use them with Cocoa/Objective-C. You can use C libraries directly and C++ ones with Objective-C++ or using a C wrapper.

Or are you worrying about the license? Many parts of FFmpeg are LGPL and can be used from proprietary applications.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about iPhone, but gstreamer is pretty portable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [OpenAL](http://connect.creativelabs.com/openal/default.aspx) or [Ogg](http://www.xiph.org/ogg/)?  I haven't used either personally but it's a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

TuneIn Radio uses code from FFmpeg and LibMMS, both licensed under the LGPLv2.1. Source code, including modifications, for both libraries can be downloaded here
http://tunein.com/mobile/ios/tunein_radio_source.zip